# How to backup photos from a broken screen galaxy S4? Help!

Tags: backup, data-recovery, photos, broken-screen

i have the same problem of many users here :-( 
My s4 has fallen and now the screen is broken: touch is black and not responsive, no way to revive it.I have tried with adb and installed Samsung latest usb drivers:
so adb is able to see my phone and it displays a serial with numbers and letters with "recovery" near it; i am able to make copies of folders(sdcard for example) with "adb pull" from phone to my pc but something is wrong cause they are all empty! Can anyone give me some help??

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you already checked with our [broken-screen tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info) and its first-aid and links? Especially see the *Data Recovery* section at its end.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try more stuff on the command-line side using ADB, I think you can definitely recover them. Link [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) for the appropriate documentation. You might also want to try [Kies](http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/) from Samsung to recover stuff. But, most of all, you should install Google Photos if you really care about your pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Check for this solution [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2786395). I've successfully backed up my data, apps and more, with broken Galaxy S4 screen too, using this tool.